# Making yaml template configurable

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am new to YAML and DevOps so my apologies if I am not able to frame question correctly.

I have multiple yaml template and one is calling other yaml file.

For example - main.yaml is calling app-build.yaml and app-build is calling app-deploy.yaml.

there are few setting in app-build yaml file which i want to make it configurable, for example, below task in app-build yaml i want to make  **"enabled"** value configurable.what is the right way of making it configurable? should i parameterise it and pass from one file to another or should i declare a seperate variable file and read values from there?

```
- task: AzureAppServiceManage@0
    displayName: 'Swap Slots'
    enabled: true
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.azureServiceConnection }}
      WebAppName: '$(appServiceNameEnv)'
      ResourceGroupName: '$(appRSGNameEnv)'
      SourceSlot: Next
```

Answer (score 1):

> i want to make "enabled" value configurable.

The example setting you were talking about needs to set in compile time.

Let me write a demo for you:

***main.yml***

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
parameters:
- name: ENABLE
  default: true
steps:
- template: app-build.yaml
  parameters:
    ENABLE: ${{parameters.ENABLE}}
```

***app-build.yaml***

```
parameters:
- name: ENABLE
  default: false
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  enabled: ${{parameters.ENABLE}}
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Write-Host "This is app-build.yaml!"
- template: app-deploy.yaml
  parameters:
    ENABLE: ${{parameters.ENABLE}}
```

***app-deploy.yaml***

```
parameters:
- name: ENABLE
  default: false
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  enabled: ${{parameters.ENABLE}}
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Write-Host "This is app-deploy.yaml!"
```

Repository structure on my side:

[image]

Comment: I want to pass parameter to app-deploy.yaml.  main.yml -> app-build.yaml -> app-deploy.yaml , is this right way to do to pass parameter from one file to 2nd file to 3rd file? how you are passing parameter from app-build.yaml to app-deploy.yaml in above example?

Comment: @F11 Hi, I re-writed the answer. Now parameter 'ENABLE' will be pass from 1st file to 2nd file to 3rd file. See the re-writed demo. :)